# WCF the remote server returned an error (404) Not Found?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, post

I have a WCF Service that I start up in VS2015. Then Client code in another VS2015.. I keep getting "the remote server returned an error (404) Not Found" Error. When I add parameter to URL "http://localhost:53989/FileShareService.svc/UploadFile/WTM" is works fine but if I add as encoding.GetBytes I get the error.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileShareWebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadFile/{patron}",
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    void UploadFile(string patron);

}
```

Client Code Not Working:

```
     ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

        string postData = "patron=WTM";
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:53989/FileShareService.svc/UploadFile/WTM");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        //httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        // Code to write data to the stream
        using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Client Code Working:

```
      var httpWebRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:53989/FileShareService.svc/UploadFile/WTM");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: You are specifying utf-8 as your charset in the ContentType header, but using ASCIIEncoding to get your bytes. Have you tried using UTF8Encoding to get the bytes?

Comment: You are also specifying application/json in your content type header, "patron=WTM" doesn't look like json to me. Maybe try application/text.

Comment: I changed my code to:                                                                
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
     string postData = "{ \"patron\" : \"WTM\"}";
     byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);                                                                                   **Still same error!!

Comment: Make one more change. Try changing UriTemplate if you are posting json data and not getting it from URI.